# IE9 causing broken layout while trying to put divs side by side

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I am trying to find a solution as to why in IE9, my layout is broken, as you will see from the attached grab. However, in all other browsers, inc IE10, it displays correctly. I have spent the last two days trying to find a solution as to this problem and have tried many things inc various clear options. I stripped my code down to the bare skeleton, with the minimum css, but cannot find a way to repair this broken layout.

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong as I am going nuts trying to sort it. Many thanks.

Broken IE9 Layout
[image]

Correct IE10 Layout
[image]
html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
<title> ie9 test page</title>

<link href="cp.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="TopColumn">
<br /><br />
<span class="setsName">Hello, <?php echo $_SESSION['kt_name_usr']; ?></span>
<br /><br />
<span class="setSubTitle">Welcome to the Logistor customer control panel.</span>
</div>
<br />

<div id="cpContainer">
        <div id="settingsDiv">
            <p>
                <span id="setHeader">Settings</span>
                <span id="setHeaderRight" class="tooltip" title="Close"></span>
            </p>
                <hr />
                <div id="setsTitle">
                    <div id="setContainerDiv" style="float:left; width: 100%; margin: 30px 0 44px -6px; font-size: 11px; text-align: center; color: #A8A8A8 !important;">

                    <div id="setIconLeft" style="float:left; width: 32%; margin: 0 0 0 -10px;">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/smlDeptIcon.png" height="48" width="48" class="tooltip" title="This is the dept" id="setDept"></a><br />Departments
                    </div>

                    <div id="setIconMid" style="float:left; width: 33%; margin: 0 0 0 0;"">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/smlProfileIcon.png" height="48" width="48" class="tooltip" title="This is the profile" id="setProfile"></a><br />Profile
                    </div>

                    <div id="setIconRight" style="float:left; width: 33%; margin: 0 0 0 0;">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/smlChgPassIcon.png" height="48" width="48" class="tooltip" title="This is the pass" id="setPass"></a><br />Change Password
                    </div>

               </div>
        </div>
        <br />

        </div>

        <div id="DestructionDiv">
            <p><span id="destHeader">Destruction</span></p>
              <hr />
                <div id="DestructTitle">
                    <div id="destContainerDiv" style="float:left; width: 100%; margin: 30px 0 44px -6px; font-size: 11px; text-align: center; color: #A8A8A8 !important;">

                        <div id="destIconLeft" style="float:left; width: 33%; margin: 0 0 0 -10px;">
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/smlDestructIcon.png" height="48" width="48" class="tooltip" title="destruction schedule administration" id="destSchedule"></a><br />Schedule
                        </div>

                        <div id="destIconMid" style="float:left; width: 33%; margin: 0 0 0 0;"">
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/destCertIcon.png" height="48" width="48" class="tooltip" title="Destruction Certificates. Coming Soon" id="setDestCert"></a><br />Certificates
                        </div>

                        <div id="destIconRight" style="float:left; width: 33%; margin: 0 0 0 0;">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/batchDestIcon.png" height="48" width="48" class="tooltip" title="Batch destroy boxes. Coming Soon" id="setBatch"></a><br />Batch Destruction
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

css

```
#cpContainer  {
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        float:left; 
        width: 96%; 
        border: 1px solid #ccc; 
        margin-left:30px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 70px;
        -wekbit-border-radius: 8px;
        -moz-border-radius: 8px;
        -o-border-radius: 8px;
        border-radius: 8px;
    }

    #settingsDiv {

        background-color: #fff;
        float:left; 
        width: 35%;
        border: 1px solid #ccc; 
        margin:10px 10px;
        -wekbit-border-radius: 8px;
        -moz-border-radius: 8px;
        -o-border-radius: 8px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        background-image: url("../images/settingsIcon32.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 20px 7px;
        clear:right;
    }

    #DestructionDiv {

        background-color: #fff;
        float:left; 
        width: 35%;
        border: 1px solid #ccc; 
        margin:10px 10px;
        -wekbit-border-radius: 8px;
        -moz-border-radius: 8px;
        -o-border-radius: 8px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        background-image: url("../images/DestructIcon.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 20px 7px;
    }

    #FilesDiv {

        background-color: #fff;
        float:left; 
        width: 35%;
        border: 1px solid #ccc; 
        margin:10px 10px;
        -wekbit-border-radius: 8px;
        -moz-border-radius: 8px;
        -o-border-radius: 8px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        background-image: url("../images/file_icon_32.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 20px 7px;
    }

    #SideDiv {

        background-color: #fff;
        float:left; 
        width: 24%;
        border: 1px solid #ccc; 
        margin:10px 10px;
        -wekbit-border-radius: 8px;
        -moz-border-radius: 8px;
        -o-border-radius: 8px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        background-image: url("../images/ComeSoonIcon32.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 20px 7px;
        vertical-align:top;
    }

    #TopColumn  {
        background-color: #f3f3f3;
        height:130px;
        margin-top: -2px;
    }

    #setsTitle  {

        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
        color: #a8a8a8;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        line-height: 30px;
    }

    div#setsTitle a {

        /*color: #000;*/
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    div#SideTitle a {

        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #DestructTitle  {

        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
        color: #a8a8a8;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        line-height: 30px;
    }

    #FilesTitle  {

        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
        color: #a8a8a8;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        line-height: 30px;
    }

    #SideTitle  {

        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #a8a8a8;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        line-height: 30px;
    }

    div#setsTitle a {

        /*color: #000;*/
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    div#SideTitle a {

        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    div#DestructTitle a {

        /*color: #000;*/
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #setHeader{

        width: 90%;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin: 0 0 20px 60px;
        color: #3D80E4;

    }

    #setHeaderRight{

        float:right;
        margin-right: 20px;
        margin-top: -5px;
        height: 32px;
        width: 33px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #destHeader{

        font-size: 20px;
        margin: 0 0 20px 60px;
        color: #3D80E4;

    }

    #FilesHeader{

        font-size: 20px;
        margin: 0 0 20px 60px;
        color: #3D80E4;

    }

    #sideHeader{

        font-size: 20px;
        margin: 0 0 20px 60px;
        color: #3D80E4;

    }

    #setDeptShow{

        width: 90%;
        font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #a8a8a8;
        margin-left: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
    }

    #setProfileShow{

        width: 90%;
        font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #a8a8a8;
        margin-left: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
    }

    #setDestScheduleShow{

        width: 90%;
        font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #a8a8a8;
        margin-left: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
    }

    #setChgPassShow{


        width: 90%;
        font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #a8a8a8;
        margin-left: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
    }

    span.setsName{

        font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
        font-size: 22px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #3d80e4;
        margin-left: 34px;

    }

    span.setSubTitle{

        font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
        font-size: 22px;
        color: #a8a8a8;
        margin-left: 34px;

    }

    hr {
     border: 1px solid #e1e9f5;
     background: #e1e9f5; 
     width: 90%; 
     height: 1px;
     margin: 10px 0 1px 20px ;
    }

img {

    outline: none;
    border: 0;

}
```

Comment: Don't have time to look at your markup but a few notes: 1) Your doctype should not be used for new web pages since 1999 2) <link> and <br> do not have closing slashes though it's allowed but ignored.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried <!DOCTYPE HTML> but still the same. I must have tried every variation of doctypes :-) Thanks

Comment: To be clear, my notes were not to fix anything but doctypes are not something to change. It's the first thing to go on a page and never touched again. I'll try and look at this now.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to duplicate the problem on my VM.

Comment: Thanks anyway Rob. Strange thing thought, if I take out my <a> from code it works fine. Go figure.